# jQuery - How to read QR Codes with web cam?

Tags: jquery, qr-code

I am looking for information on how to read QR codes from a web cam.

We want to put web cams in our kiosks and have the user hold their paper receipt up to the web cam on the kiosk and access their info.

It would be awesome if there was a jQuery plugin for this?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need more than javascript to interact with the web cam. Perhaps an ActiveX control or some HTML 5 magic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This cannot be done using native HTML (yet?).
You could either use Flash\Silverlight to capture the web-cam output, each of them has qr code libraries ([.Net](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), [Flash](http://flash.livelytuts.com/archives/read-qr-code-with-qrcodereader-open-source-as3-library.html))

Comment: 2020 update: https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/

Answer (score 0):

There is a product in google code that is somewhat similar. I haven't tryed but I looking for something similar. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-webcamqrcode/

Answer (score 0):

There's a JS/jQuery library here: https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/

Comment: Do not bother, the link is dead now, but one can still access it via the [Way Back service](http://web.archive.org/web/20171122103322/https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/).